# How can I make googly eyes with rigid body simulation, or constraints?

Tags: animation, physics

I am trying to get a bounce effects for googly eyes on my character. I have 2 objects set up, one hollow "glass case" and a cylinder used as the "pupil". I set up rigid body on both, made the glass case animatable, and set it to use the mesh as opposed to convex hull. However, my "pupil" keeps flying outside of its glass case. It works when hitting play, but as soon as I move the glass case, the pupil eventually flys out of the case.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with constraints either, as that might be better as it would save a step in not having to bake the animation.

[Here is a link to my googly eye blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xkcqxlo72ovu5s3/Googly_Eye.blend/file)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please use https://blend-exchange.com when uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to control rigid bodies with collision-- particularly, concave collision-- is not usually a great idea.  Collision isn't all that trustworthy.  It is particularly untrustworthy when dealing with mesh collision, which is necessary for concave shapes; it is particularly untrustworthy when working with "small" objects.  You are doing both. You should be using rigid body constraints instead.

Here, I would use a generic constraint, with 0-0 angle limits, and motion away from the head limited 0,0; other axes' motion limited appropriate to the size of the eye (looks like about -0.08 to +0.08 here.)  But you should experiment with others depending on your needs.  An off center googly eye would be well served by -180 to 180 rotation in a single plane and 0,0 for all other rotation and translation limits.

Note that you have another problem in the file: you have unapplied scale.  Rigid body physics do not work right when operating on objects with unapplied scale.  Delete your keyframes and apply scale.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=qR8BWxyd" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qR8BWxyd/) Doh! You're right, I forgot to apply the scale. As soon as I did that, things got a lot less wonky. However I would still like to try it using the rigid body constraint as you mentioned. I've never used the rigid body constraint, only rigid body. I tried to set it up and follow what you said to the best of my abilities, but I'm unsure what object needs it, or both, or what object to select since it is able to select two objects. I've attached what I have so far.

Comment: @StevenDiLeo I'm sure that once you do your research, you'll get it; otherwise, you can ask a question here about how to use rigid body constraints, hopefully focused on whatever step you're getting stuck on.